# Algorithm for toggling values in a matrix

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

There's a matrix of `N`x`M`, with each element as `0` or `1`. We select a specific `r`, `c` (such that `1<=r<=N` and `1<=c<=M`) and starting from `(0,0)` to `(r-1,c-1)`, we toggle the values. That is, `0` becomes `1` and `1` becomes `0`.

Basically, each "*move*" is to toggle all the values in an arbitrary *top-left* sub-matrix of our original matrix.

I need to write a function to calculate the *minimum* number of moves such that all elements of the matrix end up at 1, but not getting how to do it. Please help.

For example, in the following matrix (N == 2 and M == 4):

```
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1
```

after doing the move `(2, 1)` we'll end up with this matrix: (note the toggled values in the first column and unchanged values in the rest of the matrix.)

```
1  1  0  0
0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Sir,I am new to programming and don't know  how to handle such problems.Still learning. :(

Comment: I don't get it, just iterate through the elements and keep toggling.

Comment: This is the second problem in 30 mins that you have asked with no sign of effort provided. Please attempt to solve these yourself first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311322/algorithm-matrix-transformation

Comment: That's the thing I am saying dude. I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SOLVE SUCH ALGORITHMS !!! Had i known how to do it, i wouldnt have asked here. :(

Comment: You could find some ideas about how to solve this in [CodeChef editorials for EFFPAINT problem](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/6549/effpaint-editorial).

Comment: If you don't even have the faintest idea where to start or what to Google for, then [so] is probably not the place for this question. We expect users to show some attempt at solving the problem themselves.

Comment: @Inisheer From what I can tell, it's the same question, just elaborated upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should give you an idea.

If you start from the right bottom corner and traverse the matrix backwards, you can get the number of 'moves'.

Lets call `move(r,c)` as pressing the button at `r,c`.

So for example, if the `N-1,M-1` entry is a zero, then you will have to press a button at `N-1,M-1`. Subsequently all entries before it shall get toggled.

Now you check this for each entry in the last row backwards. Subsequently check this for each entry in the last column backwards.

**Instead of actually toggling all the entries, you can keep a count for the number of times a 'column' is toggled while traversing a row and the number of times a row is toggled while traversing a column.**

Now decrease N by 1 and M by 1 and repeat. The present value of each entry shall be: 
`Original value ^ number of times its column has been toggled ^ number of times its row has been toggled` & 1.

Comment: Just one note: the present value of each cell will be `what_you_wrote & 1` (because `what_you_wrote` can be greater than 1 if `number of times its column has been toggled ^ number of times its row has been toggled` > 1)

Comment: Aah yes you are right. Corrected.